# Magento plural support

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, plural

anybody knows whether magento utilizes zend's plural in templates? So far haven't found any traces in the code

I want to make use of it to display 1 `review`, 3 `reviews`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Magento doesn't support this mechanism.

Comment: Ok, hopefully it will be available in Magento 2.0 Thanks for the answer!